# Prestashop v1.4.8.2 images missing after upgrade to v1.6.0 and rollback

Tags: image, upgrade, prestashop

I'm new to prestashop.
Yesterday I upgraded my prestashop dashboard with "1-click Upgrade" module from version 1.4.8.2 to 1.6.0 stable. After the upgrade the whole website template was changed and some images were missing, so i decided to rollback the versions. At first it seemed everything was OK, but today I noticed some images on the site are missing/or I might have wrong URL's to the images (I don't know how it was before).

I also did backups of database and website. I checked the URL of a missing image and it doesn't exist even in the backup folder. Any idea what is going on?

Here is an example of error i get in the browser:

> "GET http://{mywebsite}.com/img/c/sl-default-medium.jpg 404 (Not
> Found)"

**EDIT:**

I tried to run image regeneration and this error was returned:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your >request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@{mywebsite}.com and inform them of the time the >error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**EDIT2:**
300 latest error logs from cpanel:

> [Thu Nov 27 03:21:20 2014] [error] [client 164.8.7.90] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/sl-default-medium.jpg,
> referer: http://papirnicatara.com/product.php?id_product=185 [Thu Nov
> 27 03:13:53 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=10 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:53 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=10 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/6, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/3/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:43 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/3/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=8 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:13:28 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:13:28 2014] [error] [client 109.182.65.7] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:13:28 2014] [error] [client
> 109.182.65.7] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:13:28 2014] [error]
> [client 109.182.65.7] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:13:14 2014] [error] [client 164.8.7.90] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/favicon.ico [Thu Nov 27 03:10:47
> 2014] [error] [client 66.249.64.109] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/4/3 [Thu Nov 27 03:10:41 2014]
> [error] [client 66.249.64.101] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/2/1 [Thu Nov 27 03:09:32 2014]
> [error] [client 164.8.7.90] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:09:32 2014] [error] [client 164.8.7.90] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:09:32 2014] [error] [client
> 164.8.7.90] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:09:32 2014] [error]
> [client 164.8.7.90] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:08:18 2014] [error] [client 164.8.7.90] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:08:18 2014] [error] [client
> 164.8.7.90] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:08:18 2014] [error]
> [client 164.8.7.90] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:08:18 2014] [error] [client 164.8.7.90] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:33 2014] [error] [client
> 164.8.161.54] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:33 2014] [error]
> [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:06:33 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:33 2014] [error] [client
> 164.8.161.54] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:30 2014] [error]
> [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/5, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/9, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/6, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/c/sl-default-medium.jpg, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/sl-default-medium.jpg, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:30 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/4/7, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/category.php?id_category=2 [Thu Nov 27
> 03:06:27 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:06:27 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:27 2014] [error] [client
> 164.8.161.54] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:27 2014] [error]
> [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:06:23 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:23 2014] [error] [client
> 164.8.161.54] File does not exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/ [Thu Nov 27 03:06:22 2014] [error]
> [client 164.8.161.54] File does not exist:
> /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/8, referer: http://papirnicatara.com/
> [Thu Nov 27 03:06:22 2014] [error] [client 164.8.161.54] File does not
> exist: /home/papirtar/public_html/img/p/7, referer:
> http://papirnicatara.com/

Comment: Did you check the server error log?

Comment: I set Error log = ON, but i don't know where do I find it to read it..? also in the header of dashboard i don't get any notifications

Comment: I meant the Apache error log. It depends on your configuration where it is located. It's is set in the Apache config.

Comment: I updated my post, check for the error logs

Comment: Did you try to recover the site from your backup in a test environment (e.g. your local development enivronment)?

Comment: i do not use test environment

Comment: I would restore the backup locally and if it is working then I would make a copy of the production version and `diff` the two folders to see the differences.